# Sine source outputting wrong signal

Tags: simulation, pspice, orcad

I was trying to simulate a circuit on Capture CIS lite, but I kept getting an output signal which was nothing like I expected. When I tried putting the probe on the sine source, it seems like the source is actually the one outputting the incorrect signal. The simulation is a parametric sweep with the amplitude voltage as the parameter, the range is from 0.5 to 0.65 volts and the the increment 0.01 volts. As you might see, I have deleted the AC parameter but the same result occurs when assigning it a value such as 1.

The circuit, if needed is this:

[image: schematic diagram]

and the output I am getting is this:

[image: output plot]

As you can see it is completely linear, which shouldn't happen in a sine source.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your signal source frequency is \$1\textrm{kHz}\$ So you need to set the simulation time (Final time) larger than \$1\textrm{ms}\$ But now you have \$1 \mu \textrm{s}\$

Comment: God i am stupid. Thanks for pointing it out. I thought of it at a point but didn't actually change it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the time frame across the bottom of the chart.

It ranges from 0 to 1 microsecond.

Your signal generator is producing a 1kHz signal.

The chart is showing you 1/1000 of a single cycle of your sine wave.

Over that period, a sine wave looks like a straight line.   Over a short enough time period, everything looks like a straight line.

To see your sine wave, you need to extend the length of the analysis.

If you extend the time to 1 millisecond, you will see one full cycle out of your generator.

To see what your amplifier is doing, you probably need to see more cycles.  Say, 10 or 20 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It crossed my mind but didn't actually change it.